# Can't update $scope on modal close

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a controller tied to my view via routing.

Example in App.js I have the following:

```
when('/about', { templateUrl: 'views/about.html', controller: 'appAboutCtrl' }).
```

I have another controller for Modal specific actions. I need this since it is a login action that applies across pages, and for that reason, it is it's own controller versus repeating the login functionality in every controller.

My modal does what it is supposed to do, but when I close it, I need it to update the $scope on the page to show/hide an item by setting something akin to:

```
$scope.isLoggedIn = true;
```

However, the scope is not updating. I have seen something like this here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2110#issuecomment-54551321 but given the complexity of my login, I need it to be in its own controller... separate of the controller driven my view.

Here is the call to my Modal and controller specific modal in the controller tied to the view I open it from (about.html and appAboutCtrl):

```
// Open Modal for Login
$scope.login = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'appLoginCtrl',
        size: 'lg'
    });
}
```

Here is where I try to set the scope on modal close in appLoginCtrl:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
     $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
     $scope.isLoggedIn = true;
};
```

I can reload the view on modal close, but can't set the $scope as follows:

```
$scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
    $route.reload();
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    $route.reload();
};
```

How can I set the $scope on Modal close so that when I close the modal, my view registers the change? My $scope is tied to a ng-show to show/hide an item on login.

Comment: should probably have a service store a user object that can be inherited by controllers, then you would only need to update that user object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use resolve option to bind variables.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'appLoginCtrl',
        size: 'lg'
        resolve: {
            isLoggedIn: function () {
              return $scope.isLoggedIn;
            }
        }
});
```

or you can pass the parent controller's scope to the modal scope

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'appLoginCtrl',
        size: 'lg',
        scope: $scope
});
```

Comment: I got it working by wrapping my code in a $scoped function in my first controller that checks if the user is logged in and then I execute this on close since it is a scope item in my second (login) controller. When I tried to set the scope via my login controller it could not pass back to the parent from the controller tied to the modal.